# check if number is prime and which is it (c++)

Tags: c++

I am trying to get out print prime numbers and which number it is (like this: 2 is 1, 3 is 2 , 5 is 3, 7 is 4, 11 is 5 and so on...).
But i have no idea how to make my sum update when new prime number is found.
Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    int i, j, num, sum;

    num = 1;
    sum = num++;

    for (i = 2; i < 1000; i++) {

        for (j = 2; j <= (i / j); j++)

            if (!(i % j))
                break; // if factor found, not prime

        if (j > (i / j))
            cout << i << " is " << sum << endl;
    }
}
```

BTW, i know `num = 1` and `sum = sum ++;` not gonna loop, i just don't know how to loop it with prime numbers...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From what I can understand the below code should do your job

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num=0,i,j;
    for(i=2;i<1000;i++){
        int flag=0;
        for(j=2;j<=sqrt(i);j++){
            if(i%j==0){
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag==0){
            num++;
            cout<<num<<"is"<<i<<"\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output it produces is

```
1is2
2is3
3is5
4is7
5is11
6is13
7is17
8is19
9is23
```

and so on till 1000

Comment: if you are satisfied with the reply kindly upvote the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the:

```
    if (j > (i / j))
        cout << i << " is " << sum << endl;
```

with:

```
    if (j > (i / j)) {
        cout << i << " is " << sum << endl;
        sum++;
    }
```

or even (in the same line) with:

```
    if (j > (i / j))
        cout << i << " is " << sum++ << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum = 1;

for (int i = 2; i < 1000; i++) {
  bool found=false;
  for (int j = 2; j*j <= i; j++) {
    if (!(i % j)) {
      found=true; // if factor found, not prime
      break;
    }
  }

  if (!found) {
    std::cout << i << " is " << sum << std::endl;
    ++sum;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want the output like this: (like this: 2 is 1, 3 is 2 , 5 is 3, 7 is 4, 11 is 5 and so on

```
int main(){

int i, j, num;

num = 1;

for (i = 2; i < 1000; i++) {

    for (j = 2; j <= (i / j); j++)

        if (!(i % j))
            break; // if factor found, not prime

    if (j > (i / j))
        cout << i << " is " << num++ << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```